# Testing library check for element value - Testing a countdown component

Tags: javascript, testing, testing-library

I'm currently building a test for a page that has a countdown element. I already have the test checking if the countdown element is present, I wanted to make a more complex test, checking if the value changes after few seconds.

Not exactly this(because I dont think `browser.getByTestId` will return the element value ), but here is the idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
    const initValue = await browser.getByTestId(timeLeftValueContainer);
    setTimeout(() => {
        expect(browser.getByTestId(timeLeftValueContainer)).toBeLessThan(initValue);
    }, 1000);
```

Is there a way to do that with Testing Library?